# Is it possible to promote my theme or my github repositories here?

Tags: discussion

this is my first question after only reading the site question and answer.

I have done some developing and i would like to know is it possible to promote my theme here ?Its still in Beta, but i would like to hear constructive input for you guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. This is a Q&A site, where developers, programmers and even designers alike help each other by responding to questions, concerns and issues. Still, read [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) short excerpt that should answer your question.

Assuming that you will sell that theme on a marketplace, I strongly suggest you ask for feedback on that marketplace's forums - for example, if your goal is to sell it on [Themeforest.net](http://www.themeforest.net?ref=crozer), then go ahead and ask those guys for feedback; they will be more than happy to help.

Anyhow, it is really up to you what you use this site for, but trust me, if the community feels your *question* is somewhat spammy, or just for self-promotion, you will get hit.

Comment: thank you. i don't have any attention to spam this site. just looking a place to do beta/functional testing of my theme. Thank you about the themeforest.net. i will close the question